# Chef Ohai Plugin Creation - Creating a new Mash

Tags: chef

**Summary**: Why do we initialise new mashes without an equals, "=", sign?

**Details:**

I have written a custom Ohai plugin for our company specific data to be available for use by various recipes. This works fine but I am not clear about the process of creating a new mash. In the [Opscode Ohai doc](http://docs.opscode.com/ohai.html), in the "Use a Mash" section, they create a mash as follows

```
canhas Mash.new
```

this works. But why is it not

```
canhas = Mash.new
```

so somehow, without the equals sign, "canhas" is assigned a new mash. If I include the equals sign then my Ohai plugin does not work - the "canhas" nested mash/hash item is not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has a flexible (loose) syntax for calling methods and functions. These three lines are equivalent within a class:

```
self.canhas(Mash.new)
canhas(Mash.new)
canhas Mash.new
```

When you write `canhas Mash.new`, you're calling a class method on `self` called `canhas` and passing it `Mash.new` as an argument. On the other hand, when you write `canhas = Mash.new`, you're creating a new local variable called `canhas` which is not referenced in any way and does precisely nothing.